# I try to validate my form before open my modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I try to validate my form before open my modal.

But my modal open, even if a zip code is empty.

https://jsfiddle.net/4yjjmbs6/1/

```
/* ==================== ZIP Code ==================== */

function maxLengthCheck(object) {
  if (object.value.length > object.maxLength)
    object.value = object.value.slice(0, object.maxLength);
}

function isNumeric(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode(key);
  var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
  if (!regex.test(key)) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a call to open the modal in your code. Where does that happen?

Comment: the validate () function that launches the modal if the input is valid

Comment: So your problem is not the modal at all, it's actually input validation?

Comment: Yes, there is a problem in my code. I want to check both input before opening the modal. but nothing to do I do not find how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JSFiddle, change

```
if (validateEmail(email)) {
    $('#registration').modal('show');
}
```

to

```
if ($('#formNewsletter')[0].checkValidity()) {
    $('#registration').modal('show');
}
```

The above change will validate the form fields and returns `true` when all the fields are validated correctly. Hope this is what you want.

Comment: Oh, yes. Thank you !